# How reduce one day from current in Pipeline Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I can't reduce one day from current

```
def now = new Date();
print(now); // print Fri Sep 06 13:10:03 EEST 2019

print(now - 1.days); // not working

print(now - 1); // not working
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why tagged with `jenkins-pipeline`?

Answer (score 1):

the solution works. There might be 2 problems though: 
- the snippet you wrote has to be included in a `script` if you plan to execute it in a stage
- the DateGroovyMethods is not allowed to be used by default. You need administrator rights and to check the build log to allow the execution of that stuff.

The error will look like this:

```
Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DateGroovyMethods minus java.util.Date int. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
```

This is my test example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('MyDate test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def date = new Date()
                    print date
                    print date - 1

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
If you are not an administrator, you can replace the `script` block with `sh 'date -d "-1 days"'`

Comment: Yes error look like this. But in my case I can't use pipeline, stages, steps, script, sh ...
I use only node and stage

Comment: Thanks. In my case I solved problem through python script.

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
data_from = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y%m%d")

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `minus(1)` instead `of - 1`:

```
def now = new Date();
print(now);
print(now.minus(1))
```

Comment: I try used a now.minus(1) and got error:
Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DateGroovyMethods minus java.util.Date int. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.

Comment: Yup, an administrator needs to approve the script by visiting https://<myjenkins.mycompany.net>/scriptApproval/.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I solved problem through python script. from datetime import datetime, timedelta data_from = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y%m%d")

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to skip the use of `Date` entirely. `java.util.Date` is literally the oldest java implementation of date and time. The newest comes with Java 8. You can do it like this:

```
groovy:000> java.time.LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1)
===> 2019-09-08T12:07:30.835557
groovy:000>
```

You can convert from Date to LocalDateTime as well if needed.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the **wrong class** to track a moment. Use `Instant` (always in UTC), `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime` instead.

Answer (score 0):

(Java syntax used here, as I do not know [Groovy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_(programming_language)).)

## tl;dr

Subtract 24-hours.

```
Instant.now().minus( Duration.ofHours( 24 ) )  // UTC.
```

…or…

Subtract one calendar day.

```
ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ).minusDays( 1 ) )  // Time zone for Toledo, Ohio, US.
```

## *java.time*

Never use `java.util.Date`. That terrible class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310. Specifically replaced by [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

> I can't reduce one day from current

What do you mean by “one day”?

### Generic 24-hour days

Do you mean to subtract 24-hours?

```
Duration d = Duration.ofHours( 24 ) ;
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
Instant twentyFourHoursAgo = instant.minus( d ) ;
```

The [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

Run this [code live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/58SiB0).

> instant.now().toString(): 2019-09-09T18:48:17.106438Z
>
> twentyFourHoursAgo.toString(): 2019-09-08T18:48:17.106438Z

### Calendar days

Do you mean to subtract one calendar day?

This requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. It may be “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan while still “yesterday” in Toledo Ohio US.

Specify a time zone with [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) to capture the current moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region in a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime oneDayAgo = zdt.minusDays( 1 ) ;
```

Run this [code live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/58SiB0).

> zdt.toString(): 2019-09-10T03:48:17.147539+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]
>
> oneDayAgo.toString(): 2019-09-09T03:48:17.147539+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]

### Convert

If you must have a [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) object to interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert. See the new `to…`/`from…` conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
java.util.Date javaUtilDate = 
        Date.from( Instant.now().minus( Duration.ofHours( 24 ) ) ) ;
```

…or…

```
java.util.Date javaUtilDate = 
        Date.from( ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ).minusDays( 1 ) ) ) ;
```

Keep in mind that **`java.util.Date.toString` method tells a lie**, dynamically applying the JVM’s current default time zone while generating the text. One of many reasons to avoid this badly-designed class.

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]